# JSF 2.0: outputText does not print date

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have the following code:

```
<h:outputText value="#{java.util.Calendar.getInstance().getTime()}">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" type="date" />
</h:outputText>
```

which prints nothing.

When I use the following code:

```
<h:outputText value="#{group.effectiveDate}">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" type="date" />
</h:outputText>
```

it works. Does anyone know why invoking `java.util.Calendar.getInstance().getTime()` does not work? I'm using Mojarra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

java.util.Calendar.getInstance().getTime() isn't a valid EL expression.  Remember that you can only access beans through EL.

This would either be ones you explicitly create, or ones that are exposed by the container.

when the EL parser sees `#{java.util}`, it looks for a managed bean named java which has a getUtil() method.

Otherwise, it will probably say something along the lines of "Unable to find managed bean: 'java'".

Comment: D'oh. That's the problem. Still learning my way around JSF/EL etc. Thanks.